# Install package without root privileges and compiling to specific directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I would like to automatically install the required software in a shell script if it is not already present. I would like to use apt-get to install software (my example is gedit) **to a specific directory without using root privileges and without running additional program specific scripts** for compiling the software.

I tried the approach from  https://askubuntu.com/questions/193695/installing-packages-into-local-directory (last post from user172681) with the example of gedit, but it results in an error.

Example:

```
cd test

apt-get download gedit
```

> Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main gedit amd64 3.10.4-0ubuntu4 [478 kB]
>       Fetched 478 kB in 0s (3.356 kB/s)

```
ls
```

> gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb

```
dpkg -i --force-not-root --root=~/test gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

> dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory

Any ideas ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858412/errors-installing-a-deb-without-sudo-root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dpkg -i gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb --force-not-root --root=~/test
```

You have not provided the filename where it expects the filename, so it throws the error "no such file or directory".

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! While your answer appears correct, remember that you can use [Markdown formatting](https://superuser.com/help/formatting), especially it is good practice to surrond `command lines` in `` backticks, or indent them with four spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I actually made a tool for this purpose https://github.com/z3r0n3t/pkget
I really hope it helps someone just see the readme